# Ignore Include in Many to Many relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

```
var listas = await _context.Listas
    .Include(x => x.ListasXPessoas)
    .ThenInclude(p => p.Pessoa)
    .SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ListaId == id);
```

Listas has a many to many relationship with Pessoas through the ListasXPessoas table. Is it possible to not show or ignore the `Include()` data, displaying directly the `ThenInclude()` data?

Comment: You can display anything you want, but you can't tell EF to include the second level only. Hard to imagine what the object graph should look like. You get one `Lista` object, where would its `Pessoas` be?

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, you cannot perform the query without the include.  But, you can choose to filter the elements of listas you display where you perform that step.  You could even define a new object for display only if it helps readability and reusability